# onClick show the next page

Tags: php

I am creating a page pagination however I am stuck on the for loop.  Currently it shows all links from 1 to 99.

How can I make it so that it only shows one number per click as I am wanting to create a "next" button.

Do I have to involve jQuery?

**Code:**

```
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= 99; ++$i) {

echo '<li><a href="example-' .$i. '">Next</a></li>';
}

?>
```

Comment: The title is misleading. It suggest a JavaScript, but the code is PHP only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you just need this:

```
<?php
if($_GET['page'] >=99){
 exit('ran out of pages');
//no idea what you want here :-)
}

if(empty($_GET['page']) OR !is_int($_GET['page'])){
$_GET['page']=0; //or maybe you want 1, depends on usage
)

$next=$_GET['page']+1;
echo '<li><a href="example.php?page=' .$next. '">Next</a></li>';
?>
```

Comment: I am guessing the check would be an if statement?

Comment: There should be a note about validating values from $_GET.

Comment: I was thinking about `(int)($_GET['page']+1)` . The string injections could be very dangerous. Someone can add a malicious JavaScript to site.

Comment: is_int() is doing that